# Kendo UI: when opening a window I want to replace the one I am in, not open a new one

Tags: kendo-grid

When the user double clicks on an item in my grid I want open the item in the same window, not another window.

My code is like this:

```
// Double Click On row
    $("#grid").on(
            "dblclick",
            " tbody > tr",
            function() {
                var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
                var row = grid.dataItem($(this));
                window.open("xpFormPC.xsp" + "?key=" + row.unid + "target=_self");
            });
```

I am putting a "target=_self" out there but it always opens in another page.

Comment: You should accept your own answer since you found the answer yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this with the following code:

```
    window.location.replace("xpFormPC.xsp" + "?key=" + row.unid + "target=_self");                  
            //window.open("xpFormPC.xsp" + "?key=" + row.unid + "target=_self");
```